# How to write pass input into this specific Unix Scripting

Tags: bash, unix, github-api

I am trying to make this commands, which can create a repo in my own github account.

```
#!/bin/bash
a=$1
curl -u 'MYNAME' https://api.github.com/user/repos -d '{"name":$a}'
```

But it does not work as I expected. The point is that, how can I pass $1, which is the first argument, into $a.

By the way, this manual code works:

```
curl -u 'MYNAME' https://api.github.com/user/repos -d '{"name":"NEW_FOLDER"}'
```

Moreover, if I makes the code like

```
curl -u 'MYNAME' https://api.github.com/user/repos -d '{"name":"$1"}'
```

the corresponding folder created will named as -1, which is not what I am looking for.

PS:
if I makes the code like

```
curl -u 'MYNAME' https://api.github.com/user/repos -d '{"name":'"$a"'}'
```

Then the above turns out to be an error.

```
shawn:~$ ./gitcp test
Enter host password for user 'MYNAME': 
{
  "message": "Problems parsing JSON",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3"
}
```

Comment: `a="$1"` and `"name":"$a"` having them inside " should do the trick.

Comment: I have tried this before. It does create a folder, but the name is -a.

Comment: have you considered then just using `"name":"$1"` ?

Comment: @fmbesteiro I tried. See my original post. the corresponding folder created will named as -1, which is not what I am looking for.

Comment: `curl -u 'MYNAME' https://api.github.com/user/repos -d "\'{\"name\":\"$1\"}\'"` what about this chunk? It escapes most special chars

Comment: @skrrgwasme the question is inappropriately considered as a duplicate question. So I cannot publish separate answer.

Comment: @PabPeter That was my bad. I misread the phrase "it turns out to be an error..." and thought you were appending a solution to the end of your question. My mistake.

Comment: @PabPeter If you edit the question to include an explanation of why the suggested duplicate is not actually correct, then it can possibly get reopened.

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
'{"name":$a}'
```

by

```
'{"name":'\""$a"\"'}'
```

See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)

Comment: Thanks @EtanReisner, I did not notice them like that

Comment: It does not work. shawn:~$ ./gitcp test
Enter host password for user 'MYNAME':
{
  "message": "Problems parsing JSON",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3"
}
shawn:~$

Comment: My password is correct. But it still says something wrong. Enter host password for user 'MYNAME':
{
  "message": "Validation Failed",
  "errors": [
    {
      "resource": "Repository",
      "code": "missing_field",
      "field": "name"
    },
    {
      "resource": "Repository",
      "code": "custom",
      "field": "name",
      "message": "name is too short (minimum is 1 characters)"
    }
  ],
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#create"
}